# Why does my IBKR (Interactive Brokers) bot sometimes not receive data?

Tags: python, ib-api

I have a bot for printing price data to csv format. Sometimes, no data has been added to the csv. This happens despite no error messages being printed in the terminal. I assume the problem is with the connection between my bot and IBKR since this issue seems to happen randomly and I'm not changing my bot code. I am not sure how to go about diagnosing the problem, and would appreciate any suggestions or information. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, this isn't easy to solve without some more direction.  It might depend on what platform you're running this (e.g. Windows is more greedy with file locks).  To start, I would suggest looking for more places to try/catch - there may be errors going unreported.

Comment: Thanks! It's on Windows, and I didn't know about file locks before, I'll investigate them. The problem is that my understanding/knowledge is still very basic so I have no idea what the places might be or how to catch them...